# Generic Class, using type as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

I have a Generic Class I created that has a signature of the following:

```
public class GenericCrud<TEntity, TDto, REntity> : 
        IGenericCrud<TEntity, TDto, REntity> 
        where TEntity : class 
        where TDto : class 
        where REntity : Type
```

My challenge is consuming\using the generic class.  For example:

```
public class QueueService : GenericCrud<Queue, QueueDto, Provider>
```

I keep receiving a compile error indicating their is not an implicit conversion between my Provider class and `System.Type`.  I've tried things like `typeof(Provider)` with no luck.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: You're specifying `REntity` should *derive* from `Type`, which isn't going to work. You can certainly pass `Provider` as a type parameter just like you do all the others; if you then want that as a `Type` within your class, use `typeof(REntity)`. Alternatively, not everything has to be done through type parameters; you can also just accept a `Type` argument in the constructor (depending on what you're doing with it). `Func<OneType, OtherType>` to pass a factory method of some sort is also an option.

Comment: If you explain "what you are trying to do" than someone can suggest if that is possible.  Code shown in the post is very strange and does not explain what you want to achieve. Note that it is very rare to take `Type` as generic argument as there rarely (if ever) are classes dervide from that one.

Comment: Well you defined `class where REntity : Type` so the object that should be passed in the generic argument REntity has to inherit from Type, which Provider doesnt.